# Complex conjugate differential equation

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am curious how the conjugate function is defined when the function itself is a differential equation.  For example:

$f(z) = \frac{dg(z)}{dz} + \frac{d^2g(z)}{dz^2}$

How then is $\bar{f}(z)$ defined?

$\bar{f}(z) = \frac{d\bar{g}(z)}{dz} + \frac{d^2\bar{g}(z)}{dz^2}$ ?

$\bar{f}(z) = \frac{d\bar{g}(z)}{d\bar{z}} + \frac{d^2\bar{g}(z)}{d\bar{z}^2}$ ?

Something else?  To be clear, I'm a novice in this field and have only ever taken introductory courses in functional analysis, so an obvious answer may not seem so obvious to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The second one. In two words, conjugate everything. As an analogy, the conjugate of $g/z$ is $\bar{g}/\bar{z}$.

Comment: Then shouldn't you have $\bar{g}(\bar{z})$ instead of $\bar{g}(z)$? Or are they the same? In the second definition, that is

Comment: @asdf Analytic $g$ satisfy $\overline{g(z)}=\bar{g}(\bar{z})$. Consider for example $g=z^2$ or $g=iz$.